# Ошибка присвоения структурной группе из несовместимого типа

Tags: linux, c, struct, malloc, clang

Я хочу выделить память для указателя типа структуры в структуре.

```
struct group{
    char *group_n;
    char *faculti;
};

struct student_info {

    struct group *group;
    
};
    int main(void)
{
    struct student_info *student = malloc(sizeof(struct student_info) * 2);
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        *(student+i)->group = malloc(sizeof(struct group));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Мне выдает ошибку

```
error: assigning to 'struct group' from incompatible type 'void *'
                *(student+i)->group = malloc(sizeof(struct group));
                                    ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Скажите пожалуйста с чем связана данная проблема и как её решить.

Comment: А что, `student[i]->group` уже не канает? *Синтаксический сахар* зря придумывали? Только хардкор?! =)

Comment: Кстати, в сях есть способ избавится от ключевого слова `struct` в имени типа. Делается это так: `typedef struct {...} StructName;`

Comment: Оператор `=` имеет практически наинизший приоритет, ниже только оператор `,`. А вот *member access operator* практически наивысший. В любом случае, *dereference operator* ниже.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
struct student_info *student
```

`student` — указатель на `student_info`.
`student+i` — указатель на `i`-й элемент массива `student`.
Далее в соответствии с приоритетами операций `(student+i)->group` представляет собой указатель на `struct group`.
После этого оператор разыменования `*` приводит к тому, что `*(student+i)->group` — это просто структура `group`.
Которой ну никак не присвоить указатель.

Это — с чем связана проблема.

Как решить?

```
(student+i)->group = malloc(sizeof(struct group));
```

или

```
student[i].group = malloc(sizeof(struct group));
```